# MAUI MyApp.WinUI isn't running properly

Tags: maui

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview where I created a plain MAUI .NET Project. The project runs on Android Emulator properly but the WinUI App doesn't run properly. It shows the message below. But I checked starting project and Debug Settings. Can anyone give me suggestions to run the MyApp.WinUI project on Visual Studio 2022 Preview?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a known limitation at this time. Have a look at [David's blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-maui-preview-7/) at the end

> At the time of release, we are troubleshooting the latest [Windows App SDK Single-project MSIX extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.MicrosoftSingleProjectMSIXPackagingToolsDev17) for Visual Studio 2022 and .NET MAUI to address a failure to debug. You can successfully deploy the Windows app directly and run it from the Start menu.

From Visual Studio, right-click on your WinUI project and click Deploy. That will make it show up in your Start Menu, you can start it from there. Once started, in Visual Studio you can go to the Debug menu and Attach to Process. Find the process of your app and attach the debugger.